# How to send put request based on video upload via link in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video

i have 2 uploading fields one is via uploading and another is input field, through which video can be uploaded or link be provided. My video uploading and editing is working fine. But when i come to provide link, and i click on change button, it opens a folder to upload the video.
But when i provide link and click on add button, i want that to take put request. Can anyone help me to solve this.

HTML:

```
<p class="inputimg" [ngClass]="{'video': selectedImage =='video'}">
        <input type="file" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="inputfile" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style='display: none;' />
        <label *ngIf="media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Change</label>
        <label *ngIf="!media._id" for="{{media._id}}[i]" class="img_change">Add</label>
      </p>
      <div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" >
      <span style="margin-left: 12%;">or </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about media, you can use `media.id` or whatever your field is in `*ngIf` condition.

So, your HTML can be something like:

```
<div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" *ngIf="media.id">
   <span style="margin-left: 12%;">Change</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
</div>
<div class = "type-video"  [hidden]= "selectedImage !='video'" *ngIf="!media.id">
   <span style="margin-left: 12%;">Add</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" (change)="editPinImage($event,media)" style="width: 28%;margin-right: 24%;">
</div>
```